# Fixing the size and position of ScrollViewer?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm making 'Page in Page'.

So, I attached grid and scrollviewer and frame tag.

But, when I run, scrollviewer frame's size and location is changed to the page's entire size, but I don't want scrollviewer's frame size and location changed.

So, how can I fix the size and position of scrollviewer?

Thanks for reading.

```
<Grid Margin="10,10,1477,669" BorderThickness="1">
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Margin="10" Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid>
            <Frame x:Name="MyFrame" Margin="10" />
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: You can set an fixed size to the scrollviewer.

Comment: You could use Canvas outside of `ScrollViewer` instead of Grid, and set a fixed width and height for ScrollViewer.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this,

```
<Grid Margin="10,10,1477,669" BorderThickness="1">
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="200" Grid.Row="1">
        <Frame x:Name="MyFrame" Margin="10" />
</ScrollViewer></Grid>
```

Set the height of the scrollviewer to some specific height and that should do it.

Comment: could you please elaborate as to where you want your scrollviewer to be placed in the page and its tentative height ?